# strftime with midnight formatted as '24' rather than '00'

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have a .csv with a series of timestamps with the format `HH:MM:SS`. Annoyingly, the hour is formatted with midnight represented as `24` rather than `00`.

Normally I would use: `datetime.strptime('24:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')`, but this throws a ValueError as 24 isn't recognized as a valid hour.

Is there an easy way to do this short of manipulating the string?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way using the datetime library. You can check out the source code for `datetime.strptime` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/_strptime.py); the relevant regex is on line 188. The simplest solution may be string manipulation.

```py
timestamp = '24:00:00'

if timestamp[:2] == '24':
    timestamp = '00' + timestamp[2:]

#as a oneliner
timestamp = '00' + timestamp[2:] if timestamp[:2] == '24' else timestamp
```

Comment: But you have to add a day to the result. 2020-09-09 24:00 is 2020-09-10 00:00.